# TypeError: Cannot read property 'HttpProvider' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
import * as Web3 from 'web3'
import { OpenSeaPort, Network } from 'opensea-js'
const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io')
```

Hi guys, Recently started studying Node.js and ran into a problem:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'HttpProvider' of undefined
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: When you have such error, go to the Type's constructor and check if `providers` is even exist

Comment: console.log(Web3.providers) shows 'undefined'

Comment: You need to look into your `web3` library's documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the syntax of your import:

```js
import Web3 from "web3";
```

Alternatively, you can also leave your import as it is and first access the `default` module.

```js
const provider = new Web3.default.providers.HttpProvider(
  "https://mainnet.infura.io"
);
```